# Angular data type unexpected behavior

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm developing a master-details user interface, so to represent each detail row I defined this class:

```
export class CompraDetalle {
  idMaterial: number;
  cantidad: number;
  costoUnitario: number;
  subtotal: number;
}
```

Here is some of the code from the HTML file of my component:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Material</mat-label>
    <mat-select placeholder="Selecciona Material" [(value)]="idMaterialSeleccionado">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let m of (materiales$ | async)" [value]="m.idMaterial">
        {{m.nombre}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Cantidad [Kg]" [(ngModel)]="cantidad">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Costo Unitario [Bs / Kg]" [(ngModel)]="costoUnitario">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Subtotal [Bs]" [(ngModel)]="subtotal">
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="agregar()">Agregar Detalle</button>
```

And here is part from the TS file of my component:

```
export class CompraDialogoComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  total: number;
  // detail
  idMaterialSeleccionado: number;
  cantidad: number;
  costoUnitario: number;
  subtotal: number;

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['idMaterial', 'cantidad', 'costoUnitario', 'subtotal', 'acciones'];

  compraDetalleListTable: MatTableDataSource<CompraDetalle>;

  compraDetalleList: CompraDetalle[];

  constructor(
    ...
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    ...
  }

  agregar(): void{
    console.log(`this.idMaterialSeleccionado typeof: ${typeof this.idMaterialSeleccionado}`);
    console.log(`this.cantidad typeof: ${typeof this.cantidad}`);
    console.log(`this.costoUnitario typeof: ${typeof this.costoUnitario}`);
    console.log(`this.subtotal typeof: ${typeof this.subtotal}`);
    if (!isNaN(this.cantidad) && !isNaN(this.costoUnitario) && !isNaN(this.subtotal)){
      let compraDetalle = new CompraDetalle();
      compraDetalle.idMaterial = this.idMaterialSeleccionado;
      compraDetalle.cantidad = this.cantidad;
      compraDetalle.costoUnitario = this.costoUnitario;
      compraDetalle.subtotal = this.subtotal;
      this.compraDetalleList.push(compraDetalle);
      console.log(this.compraDetalleList);
      this.compraDetalleListTable = new MatTableDataSource(this.compraDetalleList);
      this.cantidad = null;
      this.costoUnitario = null;
      this.subtotal = null;
    }
  }

  getTotalCost(): number {
    return this.compraDetalleList.map(t => t.subtotal).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
  }
}
```

I am using the function `getTotalCost` to sum `subtotal` field from all detail rows but if I enter `10` and `20` for this field, the sum calculated is `1020` despite the fact this field (a the others) was defined as a number.

Then I wanted to know the data type that was coming from the UI for these fields, as you can see in the first lines of agregar function, and the result was this, what explains wrong :

```
this.idMaterialSeleccionado typeof: number
this.cantidad typeof: string
this.costoUnitario typeof: string
this.subtotal typeof: string
```

So I tried to convert these fields to numbers using parseFloat function but an error is produced that says only string parameters can be parsed.

Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input matInput placeholder="Cantidad [Kg]" [(ngModel)]="cantidad">
```

Will produce a string unless you specify it should be of type `number`. Thus the `typeOf` gives you string. TypeScript though does not know this, it just looks at how you have defined `cantidad` and concludes...

*"hey, the developer has defined `cantidad` as a number, I cannot parse that to a number, it already is!!"*.

So you need to change the type or change the input to type `number` (and do not parse it).

TypeScript does not check types on runtime (as it is compiled to JS), TypeScript is there to help the developer during development to make coding easier as it checks types in the compiler for TS code and telling when you are doing something wrong, as in this case, trying to use `parseFloat` on something you have defined as a number.